# Find the projection matrix $P$

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem projects $b=(b_{1},...,b_{m})$ onto the line through $a=(1,...1)$.The horizontal line $\hat{b}=3$ is closest to $b=(1,2,6)$ Find the projection matrix $P$.

So $p$ $=(3,3,3) = P(1,2,6)$, correct? But how do I go about solving for the projection matrix? I know the formula $P = a(a^{T}a)^{-1}a^{T}$, so do I just plug in $a=(1,1,1)$ into the formula?